# Classify a language as Turing-recognizable or co-Turing-recognizable

Tags: turing-machines

I have this language

```
L = {<M> | M is a TM that accepts w whenever it accepts w^R}
```

I was able to prove that this language is undecidable.

But is this language Turing-recognizable or co-Turing-recognizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language is RE if a TM can halt-accept on all strings in the language. A language is coRE if a TM can halt-reject on all strings not in the language. For `L` to be RE, we would need to be able to tell that TM always accepts `w^R` when it accepts `w`. For `L` to be coRE, we would need to be able to tell that TM accepts some `w` but not the corresponding `w^R`. It is neither RE nor coRE.

- It is not RE because if a particular TM happens to accept the empty language, and therefore belongs to `L`, there is no way to recognize this fact. A recognizer for our language would allow us to recognize TMs that accept the empty language, an impossibility.
- It is not coRE because if a particular TM happens to accept a language consisting of a single non-palindromic string, and therefore doesn't belong to `L`, there is no way to recognize this fact. A recognizer for our language would allow us to recognize TMs that accept a single non-palindromic string, an impossibility.